# View Pdf From Realtime Database Flutter Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/hello/Courses.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';


 
class ViewCourses extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewCourses({super.key});

  @override
  State<ViewCourses> createState() => _ViewCoursesState();
}

class _ViewCoursesState extends State<ViewCourses> {
 Query dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Students');
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Students');
  
  Widget listItem({required Map student}) {
    if (!mounted) return Container();
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          height: 300,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 200, 0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                (student['Course'] ?? "").toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                (student['Title'] ?? "").toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                (student['CreatedBy'] ?? "").toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
              Text(
              (student['file'] ?? "").toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                     
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 6,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      reference.child(student['key']).remove();
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.red[700],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // Launch the URL in the default browser
                    await PDFDocument.fromURL(student['file']);
                  },
                  child: Text('Open URL'),
                  
                ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Fetching data'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
          query: dbRef,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index) {
 
            Map student = snapshot.value as Map;
            student['key'] = snapshot.key;
 
            return listItem(student: student);
 
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Hey developers i have trying to view the file url which is in realtime database in firebase to view it on the app i am going to upload pdf on the realtime database and i have currently did this to let the user launch the url when they click on open url but i dont want the user to launch the url but i want the user to view the pdf through the link can you help me to solve this much thanks

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // Launch the URL in the default browser
                    await PDFDocument.fromURL(student['file']);
                  },
                  child: Text('Open URL'),
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you're fetching from FRD  and what's the error you're getting?

Comment: i am not getting any errors the data i am fetching are 3 just text fields and a file url i just want to open the file url with a pdf plugin rn i am currently using a url launcher to launch the url so i just want to view the url file which a pdf within the app thanks for replying